# RegDBGetKeyValueEx returns -1

Tags: installscript

I am using below installscript code to identify whether SharePoint is installed or not. but its not working. The function returns -1. Not sure what is the issue.  can someone please help? I want to do below steps

1. Reach to this registry location first ""SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0""
2. Read Name "SharePoint" and its value "Installed"

refer attached image.

```c
function IsSharePointInstalled()
STRING szKey, svValue, szName;
NUMBER nvType, nvSize;

begin           
    RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);        
    szKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\Web Server 
             Extensions\\15.0";         
    szName = "SharePoint";          

    if(RegDBKeyExist (szKey) >=1) then          
        MessageBox("Key found", INFORMATION);       

    if(RegDBGetKeyValueEx(szKey, szName, nvType, svValue, nvSize) < 0) then
        MessageBox("Failed to get value", INFORMATION);
    else                        
        MessageBox("Successfully got value", INFORMATION);
    endif;
   endif;

RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT);                 
end;
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYcRt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

***Installscipt***: Where is your value located? Have you accounted for the `64-` versus `32 bit` sections of the registry?

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`

[**Perhaps investigate the 64-bit option here**](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefRegDBSetDefaultRoot.htm?Highlight=REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY) (`REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY`) if you need the 64-bit section of the registry.

---

***AppSearch***: for a simple registry retrieval like this, you could use [AppSearch](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/FAQRegistryReadData.htm?Highlight=AppSearch) instead ([System Search View](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpAppSearchView.htm)). I don't have the time to make a sample for that right now. You can also see the [System Search View / Wizard](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/SystemSearchWizard.htm).