# A way to check if registry exist on machine in Installscript

Tags: registry, installshield, installscript

I want to check if a registry exists on a machine before I rename a file. 
The registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Mauler Group, LL\RSS-FS]
```

This is my function to check:

```
szRoot = WOW6432Node\Mauler Group, LL\RSS-FS;
if (RegDBKeyExist ( szRoot )< 0) then
MessageBox ("Error", SEVERE);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Perhaps investigate the 64-bit option here**](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefRegDBSetDefaultRoot.htm?Highlight=REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY) (`REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY`) if you need the 64-bit section of the registry. I can't really test this at the moment. [Perhaps see this github.com code](https://github.com/tx4x/vt/blob/d1a0b0afa5b1500eee6dfe5191870868f24135f8/vtArtoolKit/installer/ARToolkit/Script%20Files/funcs.rul).

---

***Some Links***:

- [RegDBGetKeyValueEx returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694678/regdbgetkeyvalueex-returns-1/50697805#50697805)